# Proving $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Can someone please tell me if my argument strong enough. I feel as if there is a more efficacious way of proving the problem. Perhaps through contradiction? But with that method, I still end up with a sequence that does not converge and does converge, which confuses me. Thank you.

$\def\N{{\mathbb N}}$

> Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers and $x$ a real number. Suppose every subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ has a subsequence, which converges to $x$. Prove $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x$.

---

$\textit{Proof.}$ Let $\{x_{2n}\}$ and $\{x_{2n+1}\}$ be two subsequences of $\{x_n\}$, which converge to $x$. Hence, it follows that every subsequence is either in $\{x_{2n}\}$ or $\{x_{2n+1}\}$. Given some $\epsilon >0$, there exists $m_1, m_2 \in \N$ such that $|x_{2n} - x| < \epsilon$ for all $n\ge m_1$ and $|x_{2n+1} - x| < \epsilon$ for all $n\ge m_2.$

Now, suppose $n$ is even, and let $n = 2k$, where $k\in \N$. Then $|x_n - x| = |x_{2k} - x| < \epsilon$ for all $k\ge m_1$. So, $n=2k$ implies $n\ge 2m_1$. Therefore, $|x_n-x| < \epsilon$ for all $n\ge 2m_1. \hspace{10pt}  (1)$

Next, suppose $n$ is odd, that is, let $n=2k+1$. Then $|x_n-x| = |x_{2k+1} - x| < \epsilon$ for all $k \ge m_2$. Moreover, $n=2k+1$, which implies $n\ge 2m_2 + 1$. Therefore, $|x_n-x| < \epsilon$ for all $n\ge 2m_2 + 1. \hspace{10pt} (2)$

Let $m = \max (2m_1,2m_2 + 1).$ Therefore, from (1) and (2) we arrive at $|x_n-x| < \epsilon$ for all $n\ge m.$ Then $x_n \to x$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$. Thus, $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof is not correct, since it assumes that both sequences $(x_{2n+1})_{n\in\Bbb N}$ and $(x_{2n})_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converge to $x$.

Suppose that $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ does *not* converge to $x$. Then there is a $\varepsilon>0$ such than, for every $N\in\Bbb N$, there is some $n\geqslant N$ such that $|x_n-x|\geqslant\varepsilon$. So, there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$ of the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ such that $(\forall k\in\Bbb N):|x_{n_k}-x|\geqslant\varepsilon$. But that subsequence must have a subsequence that converges to $x$. There's a contradiction here.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to write the proof is by contradiction :

Suppose that $(x_n)$ does not converge to $x$. Then there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ and a subsequence $(x_{\varphi(n)})$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $$|x_{\varphi(n)}-x| \geq \varepsilon$$ By hypothesis, $(x_{\varphi(n)})$ has a subsequence $(x_{\varphi \text{ }\circ \text{ } \psi(n)})$ converging to $x$. But letting $n$ tend to $+\infty$ in
$$|x_{\varphi \text{ }\circ \text{ } \psi(n)}-x| \geq \varepsilon$$
you get $|x-x| \geq \varepsilon$, which is absurd.